# How will the world learn of Monero?

Tags: development, forum-funding-system, monero-research-lab, education

I do my part in sharing the Monero technology with those I know, of whom I think may be interested.

However, when I was introduced to Monero a few months ago, I found quite a bit of misinformation regarding the Monero platform. Is there any talk of "hiring" a community representative to create video blogs/ pod casts?

If not, what energy is directed towards Monero education?

Comment: Perhaps the world will learn of Monero through SE Hot Network Questions :P

Comment: You really need a "someone was hacked for millions of dollars" scandal like Bitcoin and Ethereum.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There have been some conversations about the need for producing professional looking Monero videos. Some videos have been produced from volunteers within the Monero community and from organizers or participants of events where a Monero developer has spoken but more are needed. Here is some existing audio and visual content produced by volunteers:

- [MoneroEric](https://moneroeric.com/) [education videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7BnZXYCcD4qVaEVcoT79DQ)
- [gingeropolous](https://www.reddit.com/user/gingeropolous) [education videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6AgEvNeIFw3fiEzRQ_Yswg)
- [fluffypony](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people) at [On Chain Scaling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mM2ra-LzMQk)
- [fluffypony](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people) at [Arnhem Bitcoin City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVlQE-ObEXk)
- [fluffypony](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people) at [Bitcoinference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEVm1dMn5Ks)
- [LetsTalkBitcoin](https://letstalkbitcoin.com/) - [Understanding Monero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4E6ftNOe0Io)
- [fluffypony](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people) at [BitcoinUncensored](https://soundcloud.com/bitcoinuncensored/e20-christmas-poo-122215#t=1:00:00)
- [fluffypony](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people) at [SatoshiRoundtable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKd7F-10lxM&feature=youtu.be&t=6m)

For technical users, the most informative educational content is provided by the papers written by [Monero Research Lab](https://lab.getmonero.org/) mathematicians.

While donations can be made directly to those who produce videos, use of the [Forum Funding System](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/82/how-is-monero-development-funded) is highly encouraged. Community consensus seems to indicate a focus on producing more content after the release of the official GUI at which time Monero will be more welcoming to newcomers without technical backgrounds.

There are many aspects to community education, this Stack Exchange site being a prime example that required a large amount of community support. So far only Bitcoin, Ethereum and Monero have been able to successfully meet the requirements of proposing and launching a SE site. [No amount of money](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) can purchase the educational materials provided on Monero SE.

> Unfortunately, we no longer offer a subscription service or license the software to host Stack Exchange sites. Stack Exchange sites can only be created via the community-driven process at Area 51. We offer neither "white-label" services, nor the ability to bypass Area 51 to create sites through partnerships.

Monero community members are encouraged to help produce educational materials such as user guides and additional [Moneropedia entries](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/how-can-i-edit-a-moneropedia-definition-or-add-a-new-one). So far most content has been created by volunteers but usage of the Forum Funding System has gradually increased over time and I expect that trend to continue.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any talk of "hiring" a community representative to create video blogs/ pod casts?

There is plenty of talk, though the best talk is what is coming out of you. And while hiring *is* possible, the best efforts come from those who, for better or worse turn of phrase, believe. There's no other way to put it. Well, perhaps there is. But its passion thats necessary to drive something. Passion that drove bitcoin from the nascent insight of distributed consensus protocols to a financial technology that will revolution civilization by extricating fidicuary responsibility from the consciousness of man, offloading it into a synthetic natural system. And its passion that has been and will be driving Monero out of the depths of the human condition into a reality that, for better or worse, will undergo the tests of time and prove its worth on this vast tapestry of time.

Its incredibly hard to hire passion.

> If not, what energy is directed towards Monero education?

You. You are the energy.

Answer (score 6):

It appears the world will learn of Monero largely the same way it learned of Bitcoin, as a currency for use on illegal Darknet marketplaces.

[Wired posted an article about 16 hours ago](https://www.wired.com/2016/08/security-news-week-hillary-clinton-didnt-delete-emails-super-deleted/), containing the following:

> This week, the dark web market site AlphaBay started accepting Monero, a cryptocurrency with an even bigger emphasis on anonymity than Bitcoin. Monero, which was first conceived in 2012 and developed in 2014, relies on some Bitcoin-like attributes, such as a blockchain and mining, but it isn’t built on Bitcoin’s source code. Instead of static usernames and wallet addresses, Monero generates unique addresses and “viewkeys” for each transaction so it’s harder for a third-party to see the details of a deal. Monero also does something called coin “mixing,” which groups transactions by size over a period of time. This makes transaction harder to trace. After the news broke, Monero’s price increased 200 percent.

Comment: "harder to trace" ugh. IMPOSSIBLE to trace!

Comment: @RenéG To be fair, only time will bear that out, and history has repeatedly shown that no crypt system is impossible to crack.  The implication that BitCoin was hard to track in the first place was much more cringe-worthy.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment very few people are more than peripherally aware of Monero's existence.   Nothing will focus people's attention more than the recent rise in the market cap.  Though it may be wrong headed logic, when people hear of something going up 300% they often think - 'oh I should get on board that train' , or at least 'I need to find out more about this'