# How will Monero core developers get funded?

Tags: core-development-team, development-funding

How will Monero core developers get funded and is there a way to donate to core developers for developing Monero, and what are the future plans for funding for Monero core developers?

Comment: I think this question is already answered here: http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/82/how-is-monero-development-funded by legendary user36303

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of interesting info on the monero site. Specific to your question is [this](https://getmonero.org/getting-started/donate/) page.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Did you just penalize me for my answer? I am not a paid customer care operator here, nor is anyone else. Just cuz people are lazy it doesn't mean I am going to run around filtering, copying and pasting things for people. My response may have helped a number of people, but I will no longer bother to answer questions if I am not in the mood to spoon feed the lazy (which is not often).

Comment: I only penalize bots and spammers; and you are neither. If you disagree with my actions, feel free to open a discussion on [meta](http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com) and state why do you think my behaviour is unfair. This will allow third parties to comment on the issue and we will be able to find a community consensus on how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: I saw a -2 for my response around the time you posted so I assumed it was you. If not, I apologize for assuming.